# Fetch metadata on SQL Server 2008 - extremely slow

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, schema, metadata, performance

We moved from SQL Server 2005 to 2008 earlier this year, and after the upgrade we noticed that fetching the metadata for tables and views along with all of their respective columns takes about 15 minutes on 2008 compared to what used to be nearly instant on 2005.

In a nutshell, here is the basic java code that takes 15 minutes to complete and slams our server utilization at near 100%. The schema variable is a reference to an internal object that holds the information returned from this query.

```
Connection con = db.open();
DatabaseMetaData metaData = con.getMetaData();
String types[] = { "TABLE", "VIEW" };
ResultSet resultSet = metaData.getTables(null, null, "%", types);
while (resultSet.next())
{
   schema.addTable(tableName);

   ResultSet columnSet = metaData.getColumns(null, null, tableName, "%");
   while (columnSet.next())
      schema.addColumn(tableName, columnSet.getString(4));
   columnSet.close();
}
resultSet.close();
```

We've searched google pretty hard on this issue, it appears that the 2008 R2 release was supposed to resolve some schema loading performance issues. Short of paying for an expensive upgrade, does anybody else have any good ideas on how to improve the performance of this query?

FYI - we are using the latest jTDS driver. We've also noticed similar performance when using Microsoft's Java driver.

Comment: Have you looked on the DB logs to see what it's doing on the DB side?  Also can you get the driver to output exactly what it's trying to do?

Comment: Yes, the call to sp_columns on the DB side is taking an average of .7 seconds per table. We have 1,354 tables and views, which comes out to about 15.79 minutes. So the sp_columns call is where the issues are. We could write our own stored proc to do this work much faster by fetching from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, but the idea behind calling it this way however was to keep our product database agnostic. We will go the stored proc route if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

See [this post](http://www.sqlmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/sql-server-programming/74464/sp-columns-running-slow) and try switching database compatibility level to 100 for SQL Server 2008. Maybe if you moved the database from 2005 to 2008 the performance hit is coming from there.